# Doubts with Attach property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Well, the title is not very descriptive because they do not how to name what I'm looking for. I'll try to explain it as best I can.

In the .xaml file, a control (Suppose a textbox), if you type "Text", this can not be used again property. If we write by hand, the compiler displays an error. Good already explained why I think it's now easier.

Suppose now that I have two (DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ... ...) with the name "Propiedad_1" and "Propiedad_2" is possible, if I'm already using one, the other can not be used in the same control and vice versa?

2) Another question, within a dependency property of type string, is it possible to check if the String changed at some point (around trying to not use a variable and then comparing), I need to avoid spending a TexBox and avoid the textbox.TextChanged event.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is what I have now.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FilterSource", typeof (TextBox), typeof (ListViewExtension),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnTextBoxTextChanged));

public static TextBox GetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj)
{
    return (TextBox) dObj.GetValue(FilterSourceProperty);
}

public static void SetFilterSource(DependencyObject dObj, TextBox value)
{
    dObj.SetValue(FilterSourceProperty, value);
}

private static void OnTextBoxTextChanged(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listView = dObj as ListView;
    var textBox = e.NewValue as TextBox;

    if ((listView == null) || (textBox == null)) return;

    textBox.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs tcea)
    {

        var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
        if (view == null) return;
        view.Filter += item =>
        {
            ...
            ...
            ...
            ...
        };
    };
}
```

**In .XAML**

```
    <TextBox Name="TxtFilter"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Filter, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CharacterCasing="Upper"/>

<ListView Margin="0,5,0,0"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}"
          tools:ListViewExtension.FilterSource="{Binding ElementName=TxtFilter}">
```

**In ViewModel**

```
public string Filter
{
    get { return _filter; }
    set
    {
        if (_filter == value) return;

        _filter = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

What I need now is change the use of a "TextBox" by a string.

```
tools:ListViewExtension.FilterSource="{Binding Filter}"
```

Comment: You are trying to filter a listview based on the value of textbox? [This example](http://grantwinney.com/using-a-textbox-and-collectionviewsource-to-filter-a-listview-in-wpf/) might help.

Comment: @mike z, Hello , thank you, but no. That 's what I have , I want to do but without the TextBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is fairly hard to understand, due to the lack of [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as the poor English. The latter is understandable (though you must still do what you can to ensure you're communicating as well as possible), but the former definitely should be addressed.

Lacking those improvements, I will guess that your questions (both…for future reference, please do not post two different questions in the same post) amount to the following:

> 1. I have two attached properties, which I would like to make mutually exclusive in the XAML editor. Is this possible?

No. The behavior you're seeing applies only to a single property. The editor will complain if you try to set the same property more than once. But it's easy for it to do that, since all it has to do is check whether that property was already used in the element.

For two different properties that are supposed to be mutually exclusive, there's not any feasible way to modify the editor or compiler's behavior to check this.

As an alternative, consider implementing the two mutually-exclusive values as a single property, where that property can accept two different subclasses of a given type, and where those subclasses each represent one of the two mutually exclusive property types.

> 2. Can I optimize property updates, so that if a new value is assigned that is actually the same as the current value, no "property changed" event is raised?

Whether this is possible depends on how your code is actually written. In WPF, binding is supported through the use of `DependencyProperty` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Neither of these would imply a `TextChanged` event in an object for a `Text` property, which you stated is the event you don't want raised.

Note that in general, `DependencyObject.SetValue()` will suppress change notifications if the effective value (after coercion) has not actually changed. Note also that in most other cases, extra change notifications would not normally be a real performance issue.

Lacking a good code example, not much more advice on that second question can be offered.

If you feel that these answers don't reasonably or usefully address your questions, please improve your post so that it is more understandable.

**EDIT:**

With respect to the first question, and based on the code snippet you've provided (not complete), I would say that the simplest approach would be to make `FilterSource` have type `object` instead of `TextBox`, and then in `OnTextBoxTextChanged()`, check the type of the new value and handle appropriately. I.e. if it's a `TextBox`, do what you're doing now (mostly…see **(*)** below), and if it's a `string` instance, just configure the view's filter directly instead of putting the configuration into an event handler.

**(*) note:**

I see at least two areas of improvement in your `OnTextBoxTextChanged()` method:

1. There is no need to rebuild the `Filter` event handler just because the text's changed. Instead, you can just call `Refresh()` on the view. So in that approach, you would implement the event handler for the `Filter` event to always retrieve the `TextBox.Text` property value for filtering. You would subscribe to the event once, and then the event handler for `TextChanged` would just call `Refresh()`.

   In the `string` scenario, you'd use a `Filter` event handler that just filters using the `string` value, with no need to handle the (non-existent, of course) `TextChanged` event.
2. The bigger issue is that you only ever subscribe to the `TextChanged` event. If you only ever change the `FilterSource` property once, you'll never notice a problem, but it *is* a problem. If the property value is ever changed again, you should be unsubscribing the old event handler before subscribing a new one. If you make the change I describe above, where the `TextChanged` event handler is only calling `Refresh()`, the impact of this bug will be significantly reduced. But it's still a bug.

**end of note.**

As far as the second part of your question goes, I don't see a problem that needs solving. It's not clear whether you're concerned about the `TextBox.Text` property or the `FilterSource` property, but I think that neither property should generate change notifications if the newly set property value is the same as the old.

If you think differently, please provide a better code example (both **minimal** and **complete**) that illustrates clearly what *actual* problem occurs, along with a clear, precise explanation of what that problem is: how the code currently behaves, and how that's different from how you want it to.

Taking all of the above into account, I think your `OnTextBoxTextChanged()` method should look more like this:

```
private static void OnTextBoxTextChanged(DependencyObject dObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = dObj as ListView;

    if (listView == null) return;

    var view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
    if (view == null) return;

    if (e.NewValue is TextBox)
    {
        TextBox newValue = (TextBox)e.NewValue;

        view.Filter += item =>
        {
            string filterString = newValue.Text;

            // filter based on filterString, etc.
        };

        textBox.TextChanged += delegate(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs tcea)
        {
            view.Refresh();
        };
    }
    else if (e.NewValue is string)
    {
        string filterString = (string)e.NewValue;

        view.Filter += item =>
        {
            // filter based on filterString, etc.
        };
    }
    else return;
}
```

For this to work, you'll of course have to change the type of your attached property from `TextBox` to `object`.

In the above, I did not bother to address the issue of unsubscribing from the `TextChanged` or `Filter` events. If you desire to fix that particular problem, it is relatively simple: you need to unsubscribe the old handlers from the events (for `TextChanged`, only if `e.OldValue is TextBox` is true of course).

Of course, to do this you'll need to store the old event handler delegate instances on a per-`ListView` object basis, e.g. in a dictionary or maybe even just having a private attached property (similar to the `FilterSource` property, but not visible to other code). That way, you can retrieve the delegate instances later to unsubscribe them from their events.

Comment: Great...glad it helped. Please note, I forgot to mention that you'd want to unsubscribe from the view's `Filter` event on a source change as well. I've edited my edit to account for that.